# Get element by id and put it inside bootstrap col

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I have a div with an ID, this div is added to the web page by the library but i want to put this div in a col-xs-6, can i do something like `document.getElementById()` then put it in col-xs-6?

Comment: Do you want to move an object from a div to another div?

Comment: No i just want to put the div that has an ID inside col-xs-6

Comment: Does a simple `$("#DivToMove").detach().appendTo('col-xs-6');` works in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this without any framework is to use element.classList.add method.

```
var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.classList.add("otherclass");
```

Answer (score 1):

IF your using jquery then you can simply do this,

```
$('#Id_of_element').addClass('col-xs-6')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to grab this div by id and add to it bootstrap class *col-xs-6*. If so then try this:

```
var yourDiv = document.getElementById("ID");
yourDiv.className += " col-xs-6";
```